# How do I scope a VS Code custom snippet to files with ".sh" or ".bash" filename extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets, vscodium

I'm using VSCodium: ver 1.79.2, release: 23166

Example of my snippet which does not work, actually does not showing in editor:

```json
"Insert: # EOF": {
  "scope": "sh,bash",
  "prefix": "eof",
  "body": [
      "# EOF $0",
  ],
  "description": "Insert EOF"
},
```

I expect that after typing the prefix, the [eof] menu to show up with option "insert EOF"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to use language IDs in the `scope` property. The language ID that VS Code uses as a catch-all for files with ".sh" or ".bash" is `shellscript`- not `sh` or `bash`.

There's a bit of a trick you can use to discover what language IDs exist (there might be a better way I don't know of): Open a [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson), and begin typing `[` for a setting key, and then trigger autocomplete. Ex.

```json
{
  "[" // put cursor after the [ and trigger autocomplete
}
```